# Why is the array size unknown?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, embedded, stm8

I tried to program this code on an STM8 Controller:

```
#include "Imagedata.h"
void main(void)
{
    unsigned char *pArray;
    pArray=IMAGE_DATA;

    while(pArray<=(IMAGE_DATA+(sizeof(IMAGE_DATA)/sizeof(pArray))))
     { 
      SPI_SendData(SPI1,*pArray++ );
      }

}
```

Actually the array is much longer than this but it would take to much space here. The Array is defined in imagedata.c:

```
#include "imagedata.h"
const unsigned char IMAGE_DATA[]= { 0X00,0X01,0XC8,0X00,0XC8,0X00};
```

After compiling this code I get the error message: array size unknown. This refers to the line where I put sizeof(IMAGE_DATA). I don't quiet understand what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. With the code you show, you should get an error that identifier `IMAGE_DATA` is completely unknown. Do you have a declaration in your header? How does that declaration look? Does it include the size? If not, the compiler cannot know as it don't see the initializer lsit from the other C file.

Comment: The array size will only be known inside imagedata.c

Comment: Hanna,  `<=` is a problem.  `<` expected.

Comment: `sizeof(IMAGE_DATA)/sizeof(pArray)` makes no sense.  `sizeof(IMAGE_DATA)/sizeof IMAGE_DATA[0]` is better.

Comment: "This refers to the line where I put sizeof(IMAGE_DATA)." No, this refers to `sizeof(pArray)`.  Why do you want the size of a pointer?

Comment: So there's typo bugs in main and apart from that the problem isn't reproducible. You need to post how `IMAGE_DATA` is declared in imagedata.h.

Comment: @Gerhardh @Gerhardh Thank you, this helped. I forgot to include the size in my header: `extern const unsigned char IMAGE_DATA[6];`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've noticed that thanks!

Comment: You then should also include the size in the definition of the array.

Answer (score 3):

There's multiple problems here.

- Try to avoid using global variables with `extern` in the first place. Implementing setter/getter functions in imagedata.h/imagedata.c is likely a better design. Use private encapsulation whenever possible.
- In case the array in the header file is declared as `extern const unsigned char IMAGE_DATA[];` you will get the mentioned error message. This creates a reference to an array of "incomplete type". You have to type out the size explicitly like `IMAGE_DATA[6]`, meaning that it probably doesn't make sense to write `const unsigned char IMAGE_DATA[]=` in the .c file either, because you have to count the bytes anyway.
- `pArray=IMAGE_DATA;` is a constraint violation of the C language. You cannot assign a non-const qualified pointer to a const qualified array.
- `sizeof(pArray)` is nonsense since it gives the size of a pointer, not of a pointed-at item. `sizeof` a character is guaranteed to be 1 anyway, so this is all rather pointless.
- `while(pArray<=` will lead to out of bounds access, use `<`. Also use `for` loops whenever possible since tend to be more readable.
- Note `#include "imagedata.h"` vs `#include "Imagedata.h"`. This will only work on host systems where the file path isn't case-sensitive. So you create a needless non-portability issue between Windows and *nix systems. Always name sources files in pure lower case.

Proposed fixes:

```c
// imagedata.h

/* 
   Normally size_t would be used for array size, but since this is STM8 I picked a 
   byte type, under the assumption that size will not be larger than 256.
*/
const char* image_get_data (unsigned char* size);
```

```c
// imagedata.c
#include "imagedata.h"

static const unsigned char IMAGE_DATA[]= { 0X00,0X01,0XC8,0X00,0XC8,0X00};

const char* image_get_data (unsigned char* size)
{
  *size = (unsigned char) sizeof(IMAGE_DATA);
  return IMAGE_DATA;
}
```

```c
// main.c
#include "imagedata.h"
void main(void)
{
  const unsigned char *pArray;
  unsigned char size;
  parray = image_get_data(&size);

  for(unsigned char i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    SPI_SendData(SPI1, pArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Note: in case you are using some god-awfully old STM8 compiler, which might be a valid scenario, then disassemble and see if this gave decent machine code. A possible micro-optimization might be to sacrifice some of the private encapsulation for speed:

```
// imagedata.h
static inline const char* image_get_data (unsigned char* size)
{
   static const unsigned char IMAGE_DATA[]= { 0X00,0X01,0XC8,0X00,0XC8,0X00};

  *size = (unsigned char) sizeof(IMAGE_DATA);
  return IMAGE_DATA;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition looks wrong, both the end value and comparison. Try this:

```
const unsigned char *pArray = IMAGE_DATA;
const unsigned char * const pEnd = pArray + sizeof(IMAGE_DATA) / sizeof(*pArray);

while(pArray < pEnd) {
    ...
```

Note 1: `sizeof char` is by definition 1, so `/ sizeof(*pArray)` part is a bit redundant. Matter of taste if it makes code clearer or not.

Note 2: It's a common pattern, and explicitly allowed by C, to have "end" pointer which is *one* past the end of the range. Just be sure to never do `*pEnd`.

Note 3: `IMAGE_DATA` must be array for `sizeof` to work. It must not be a pointer, or an "array" parameter to function (because that is also a pointer, not really array).

Note 4: `IMAGE_DATA` is const, so you need a pointer to const. As a side note, code in this answer makes `pEnd` a const pointer to const, because the end pointer itself shouldn't be accidentally changed, but this is also a matter of taste and optional.

---

So your actual problem is, IMAGE_DATA isn't fully defined array. Either the definition must include initialization:

```
char foo[]  = { 33, , 34 , 35 }; // compliers counts size 3
```

Or with explicit size:

```
char foo[3];
```